# How to Create an Array of existing JavaFX objects

Tags: java, arrays, javafx

Is it possible to create an array of JavaFX objects that can be accessed.

Currently I have:

```java
    @FXML
    private CheckBox pc1,pc2,pc4,pc8,pc16,pc32,pc64,pc128,pc256,pc512,pc1024,pc2048;

    private final CheckBox[] pcController = {pc1,pc2,pc4,pc8,pc16,pc32,pc64,pc128,
                                             pc256,pc512,pc1024,pc2048};
```

I am trying to access these objects and flip the check box based on the value in a different array as such:

```java
    

    boolean[] bits = getBits();

    for(int i =0; i<pcController.length;i++){
        pcController[i].setSelected(bits[i]);
    }
```

I get the error:

```
Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.control.CheckBox.setSelected(boolean)" because "this.pcController[i]" is null ...
```

Edit:
So I can get the system to semi-work if I instantiate the array inside a method.

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: @kleopatra that is MRE... you create a JavaFX project and put in what I described and it willl produce the same error. Another user was able to provide an answer. This comment is just unhelpful.

Comment: _your_ problem = _your_ task to provide that example: as-is, your question is just unhelpful to future readers (though the answer certainly is ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following things happen<sup>1</sup>, in this order, when an `FXMLLoader` loads an `FXML` file:

1. The `FXMLLoader` parses the file
2. The `FXMLLoader` creates object instances corresponding to instance elements in the `FXML` file, and sets properties on those objects corresponding to property elements in the `FXML` file.
3. If there is a `fx:controller` attribute on the root element, the `FXMLLoader` creates an instance of the specified class
4. The `FXMLLoader` initializes any `@FXML`-annotated fields in the controller with the corresponding elements whose `fx:id` matches the field name.
5. If the controller has an `initialize()` method, it is invoked.

In your code, you declare your array and initialize it inline:

```
@FXML
private CheckBox pc1,pc2,pc4,pc8,pc16,pc32,pc64,pc128,pc256,pc512,pc1024,pc2048;

private final CheckBox[] pcController = {pc1,pc2,pc4,pc8,pc16,pc32,pc64,pc128,
                                         pc256,pc512,pc1024,pc2048};
```

This means the array will be assigned its value when the controller is created, which is in step 3 above. Since the 12 `CheckBox`s will not have been initialized yet (because that happens in step 4), you will create an array with 12 `null` values.

Instead, initialize the array in the `initialize()` method:

```
public class MyController {

    @FXML
    private CheckBox pc1,pc2,pc4,pc8,pc16,pc32,pc64,pc128,pc256,pc512,pc1024,pc2048;

    private final CheckBox[] pcController ;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        pcController = new CheckBox[]{pc1,pc2,pc4,pc8,pc16,pc32,pc64,pc128,
                                             pc256,pc512,pc1024,pc2048};
    }

    // ...
}
```

---

(1) This is not a complete list of the `FXMLLoader` lifecycle, but it suffices to explain what is happening in this case.

Comment: Thank you! I was unawear of the FXMLLoader lifecycle and the initialize method.